# Bot Configured for FB Messenger not working

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I created a bot and got it registered in the bot portal. i also published it in Azure using a free account. I Configured the bot to use FB Messenger, but when i send messages to the bot i get this " couldn't send retry ". Under the FB channel in bot portal it says that " There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError ". Any idea whys is this happening? Please help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try your bot with the emulator? The `InternalServerError` is the generic answer sent by the bot when there is an error on your bot code. It is a lot easier to debug with the emulator.
If your problem is specific to this channel, add Application Insights to get more details on the exception

Comment: Yup, I know: there's an internal server error occurring trying to send the message. Please share some more details, relative code and information to  enable us to help you solve this. For instance by locally testing/debugging the code instead of publishing it and seeing what happens.

Comment: it runs fine with the emulater when i debug i dont get any exceptions too. i too checked the app setting in the web.config file.

Comment: Connect application Insights to your bot in order to see the innerExceptions of this InternalServerError. With app insights you can see the Failed Requests the exceptions and the specific platform errors.

Comment: Did your bot on FB Messenger approved by Facebook?

Comment: The best approach seems to debug your incoming request. If you are lazy to add log and deploy, then you can use your localhost using ngrok or use chatbotproxy to debug with an online tool.